# Delete last value entered JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have  javascript code that will validate alphanumeric and dashes for any field it is assigned to. The regex completes successfully and the error message displays. What I would like to happen is upon hitting a key that would make the regex true it would delete the variable that set it to true (for example if someone where to hit the @ key it would only delete the @ character). Right now I have it set to erase the entire field.

```
function validateAlphaNumericField(field) {
    var value = field.value;
    var reg = /[^A-Za-z0-9-]/;
    var newVal = reg.test(value)

    if (newVal == true) {
        alert("This field must contain only alphanumeric and dashes.");
        field.value="";
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the `c#` connection?

Comment: In the event handler, you can prevent the default behavior by return false, which means that the character will not be displayed.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or not?

Comment: As a user i'd prefer it not to change values while typing as it is very annoying to me. If I entered an incorrect value then message me as field loses focus or have the background/border change to red to indicate something is wrong

Comment: @gwillie, I understand what you mean most definitely, but this is per the customer

Comment: @Shahar no I am not. This is javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can replace the unexpected characters as following:

```
var value = field.value;
var reg = /[^A-Za-z0-9-]/;
return value.replace(reg,'');
```

Comment: I had to put field.value = value.replace(reg, '')  under the alert and I got what I needed. Thanks!